# How to select first 5 rows in a table using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have writen below code to select first 5 rows using selenium webdriver. But it is not working.

```
public void testRowSelectionUsingControlKey() {
        List tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='iceDatTbl']/tbody/tr"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.click(tableRows.get(0)).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(tableRows.get(1)).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(tableRows.get(2)).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(tableRows.get(3)).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(tableRows.get(4)).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
    }
```

Comment: `But it not working.` - what do you mean? WHAT IS THE ERROR?

Comment: It's not selecting first 5 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call the method `keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)` every time you select a row from your table. Try calling `keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)` before you select all the rows and then call `keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)`.

```
public void testRowSelectionUsingControlKey() {
        List tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='iceDatTbl']/tbody/tr"));
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
               .click(tableRows.get(0))
               .click(tableRows.get(1))
               .click(tableRows.get(2))
               .click(tableRows.get(3))
               .click(tableRows.get(4))
               .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
        }
```

Comment: Above code is working fine but how can we avoid hard coding ?

Comment: Pass the number of rows you would like to select as an argument `(int row)` to the method and then run the statement `builder.click(tableRows.get(i))` in a for loop from `0` to `row-1`